# Collapsing toolbar: do not collapse when draging non scrollable RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a `CoordinatorLayout` with both `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and `RecyclerView`. When there are many elements on the list and `RecyclerView` is scrollable, action bar is being collapsed or expanded on scroll, which is fine:

[image]

However, when `RecyclerView` has only a few elements and is not scrollable, when user touches and drags it, it moves and the action bar still collapses:

[image]

How can I disable such behavior?

I need a solution where:

- if `RecyclerView` is scrollable (has many items), `CollapsingToolbar` behaves as it behaves now
- if `RecyclerView` is **not** scrollable (has few items), the toolbar stays always expanded

Here is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="net.chmielowski.collapsingtoolbarplusrecycler.ScrollingActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is normal behavior for `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, but you can disable and enable scroll property manually when try to set adapter for your `recyclerView`. some thing like this:

in my setAdapter for recycler:

```
if (objs == null || objs.size() == 0) {// zero or any number you want
        objs = new ArrayList<>();
        AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) collaps.getLayoutParams();
        params.setScrollFlags(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SNAP);
        collaps.setLayoutParams(params);// collaps is my CollapsingToolbarLayout instance
} else {
        AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) collaps.getLayoutParams();
        params.setScrollFlags(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL | AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_EXIT_UNTIL_COLLAPSED);
        collaps.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

in my case I disable scroll when list had no child, but you can compute the size of child and check if list is not scrollable disable `CollapsingToolbarLayout` scroll property.

Comment: I tested several fixes with custom appbars and recycler events., this was the only one that worked, and much simpler